# Calling a chart from different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

I have 12 charts in sheet 'A' in excel. In sheet 'B' there are 2 drop downs and based on that value I want to call a particular chart in sheet 'B'. How do I do that? Can i write a vba program for each chart? 
Pls help

Answer (score 0):

People will have downvoted this because you haven't included any information about what you have tried.

It is also not clear what you want to do. You have 12 charts on sheet A, do you want to copy one of these to sheet B when you select a dropdown option? If so, you can attach macro to the dropdown box, and use the chartobject.copy method ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839049.aspx)) to copy it to a good place in Sheet B.

You'll need to figure out a method for identifying charts based on the selection in the dropdown too. I also don't know what the second dropdown does or is supposed to do. If it is for comparing, you can attach the same macro to both and use the application.caller method to find out which dropdown invoked the macro, and position the charts accordingly.